# Python replacement for PHP's header

Tags: php, python, header

How to send a raw http header in python just like header() in PHP ?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, you'd be like:

```
def someview(request):
    # ... etc ...
    out = HttpResponse(outputstring,
        mimetype="text/html",
        status_code="302",
        )
    out['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=download.html"
    # fill in all your favorite HTTP headers here
    return out
```

... for cache-control and friends, you need to import a bunch of decorators and wrap your view functions accordingly (I forget which) -- this is because django has a caching system with which many sub-rosa bits of the framework are integrated.

I find the cache stuff confusing, but also nice. non-cache HTTP headers are E-Z.

Comment: that probably works -- but I know that the django people think that's a bad idea as they redefine sys.stdout and friends. using `print` for headers will probably break at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a list of two-tuples containing the header name and header value to the [`start_response()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#the-start-response-callable) function.

Comment: This is for WSGI applications.