# How can i open url in python like php

Tags: php, python, django, python-2.7

I have view that perform `particular action` after that `return` i just want to call `url` and that `url` will `open` in the same page

```
def googleredirect(url):
    return (url)
```

like in PHP :

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: side note: In PHP, it's a header redirect, instead of "open url"

Comment: urlopen(); in python function
get the response for the function and then print the object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only redirect then use:

```
# in views.py file
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def some_page(request):
    return redirect('http://www.example.com/')
```

But if you want to open an URL for screen scraping or some thing else, then use python's own library `urllib3` or `PyQuery` for more better DOM element search

Answer (score 0):

see here  [in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948690/python-replacement-for-phps-header)

or in python

```
redirect("http://www.example.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Django-app (@Raptor removed django tag), your view should return an instance of django's **HttpResponse**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def google_redirect(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_name'))
```