# Python CGI replacement for PHP's header function?

Tags: php, python

So i found this thread:

[Python replacement for PHP's header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948690/python-replacement-for-phps-header)

but i still couldn't find my answer, i don't understand the first answer because i don't use Django and i want to use pure python (I'm using CGI)

the second answer also doesn't give details, i tried using `start_response()` but i couldn't get it to redirect to my url, maybe i was giving it the wrong arguments

also i found another topic:

[How to redirect a page to another page in python 3 cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958834/how-to-redirect-a-page-to-another-page-in-python-3-cgi)

but again the answer is still not as good as php header because it loads the entire page then redirects it which user can notice, the header function wasn't like this and was much faster and cleaner

i also tried `webbrowser.open()`
and `webbrowser.get().open()`

but the problem is they open a new tab instead of loading it right there, even when i use the new=0 option! (not to mention some weird problem that causes it to open IE as well as chrome which we have to give full path to fix)

so if the best option is `start_response()`, can someone explain what exactly should i write?

what would be the equivalent of this php header:

```
header("location: ./index.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password");
```

Comment: You don't use Django, but what HTTP Middleware / Framework are you using ?

Comment: @Blusky I'm actually using python just for one function and then pass the result back to my php page, i basically only use pure python and want to calculate something then send a error message or success using GET just like header, I'm also using XAMPP for to run the apache server

Comment: So i have to learn Django or some other framework to achieve this or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Then, if python have no handle on the HTTP middleware, you won't be able to change anything related to the HTTP Stack.

Comment: Whatever you're using to set all of the *other* HTTP headers is what you should use to set this one.

Comment: @Sammitch   sorry I am new to web dev, how can i know what I'm using to set other HTTP headers? I'm basically using a CGI python script and passing it an input using post method in my php page, and i just want to return a simple message to that php page to display the result, and I'm not using any framework, just using the CGI library in that python script

Comment: The you need to figure out how to make that CGI library do what you want.

Comment: @Blusky So what should i do?   should i use Django to achieve something like the php header and i cant do it with pure python? the only thing I'm using in this python is the CGI library which i use to receive input from my php page using POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output of a CGI script should consist of two sections, separated
>   by a blank line. The first section contains a number of headers,
>   telling the client what kind of data is following. Python code to
>   generate a minimal header section looks like this:
>
> > https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html

```
print "Location: ./index.php?msg=Invalid+Username+or+Password"
print                               # blank line, end of headers
```

Answer (score 1):

To trigger a redirect, it is not enough to set the location header, you must also return the right status code, like this:

```
print("Status: 302")
print("Location: ./index.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password")
print()
```

In PHP, you don't have to explicitly set the status because the header function does that for you if you specify a `Location:` header.

The last print is necessary because the headers should be separated with blank line from the response body (which is empty in your case).